For an observer on a spaceship moving near the speed of light away from Earth, would Earth be moving near the speed of light in the other direction?
There is something I don't understand about time relativity in examples given in internet, television, etc. Supposedly if a spaceship takes off from Earth and moves closer to the speed of light, time would be passing slower for him from the perspective of a person living on Earth, right? But from the person in the spaceship, the Earth would be moving close to the speed of light in the opposite direction, wouldnt be? Then, how doesnt the time in the person on Earth wouldnt also be passing slower from his perspective? (and in the end, wouldnt time be passing at the same rate for both?) Where's the error in the reasoning?

Then, how doesnt the time in the person on Earth wouldnt also be passing slower from his perspective? Whose perspective, the person on earth? Or the person in the ship?

from the perspective of the person in the spaceship, since for him the Earth would be moving at the speed of light in the other direction (apparently from my poor understanding). Then since the Earth is moving close to the speed of light for the person in the spaceship, shouldnt the time in the person on Earth pass slower from the perspective of the person in the spaceship?

Those internet channels and TV shows want to attract viewers so they make everything as dramatic as possible with ships travelling at the speed of light; time slowing down for Einstein-clone space voyagers, etc. While observers passing each other at relativistic speeds would see the other's clock appear to tick slower than their own, how would people moving in opposite directions (or with just one moving away) get to see each other at all?

@Wookie but if time for one of them is moving slower, people would be older when they return to Earth. If time moves slower for both of them, they would be the same biological age

Is it a wrong interpretation of special relativity when they make in movies one person to age because the other "was traveling close to the speed of light" and the person who traveled the speed of light doesnt age? (or ages slower)

If the ship continues on forever then the time dilation is symmetric...those movies usually always include the second observer undergoing some change in reference frame usually through acceleration. This causes real age difference between the ship and earth bound observers. There are plenty of answers on here that address this part (the so called twin paradox).

It's not a wrong interpretation, Pablo. Things happen at different rates depending on the conditions.

@Triatticus ok, thanks for the orientation, I'm reading some articles now about the twin paradox. I wouldnt mind if you add some links from here that you know are right about it too

@Triatticus this is why I prefer the brother and sister Fraternal Twin Paradox.
